# Speed up multiple different updates-querys

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, orm

I am working with an application that manages a larger number of storage objects (each storing a bunch of simple variables). These objects are saved via external databases, namely MySQL and SQlite.

What I currently do is loading all objects into memory on startup (direct access is needed, lazy loading is not an option, at least at the moment). When an object's value is changed, it automatically updates itself in the database by calling the corresponding update statement in a new thread.
The database-communication is handled in pure JDBC using `PreparedStatements`, connections are not pooled, there is only one active connection at a time.

As said, I am not satisfied with the whole process as it tends to be slow when multiple operations need to be written to the database and I am looking for a way to improve this. I tried to implement a queue to use batch-operations that handle multiple updates at once, but it seems that this is only possible if I have a separated queue for each update-value which seems as a bit of overhead.
Adding a connection pool could speed up MySQL but would not change anything in terms of SQLite.

Is there anything like a best-practice in this case? Could switching to an ORM help?

Comment: It does seem like you are reinventing ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned several things that you can fix to give a huge improvement in performance:

1. Don't create a new thread on each object update (e.g., use an ExecutorService to manage a pool of threads).
2. Don't create a new connection for each object update. Use a connection pool.
3. Use more than a single thread/connection for updates (see #1 above).
4. Use JDBC batching (if the semantics of your updates allow them to be ganged together into bigger transactions).

Even just doing the first three might get you a 10x speedup.